# How to use APNs Auth Key .p8 certificate in Firebase console

Tags: firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How do you use Firebase to send push notification's using Apple's new Auth Key p8 file?

I understand how to use Apple's old p12 files to keep sending push notifications but would like to upgrade to the new Auth Key.

Here is the only other resource I could find (does not answer the question):
[How to use Apple's new .p8 certificate for APNs in firebase console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672297/how-to-use-apples-new-p8-certificate-for-apns-in-firebase-console)

Answer (score 1):

You can now upload .p8 file (APNs auth key) in your Firebase console in the same page where you upload the .p12 (APNs certificates).

[image]