# Which npm module should be used to send push notification to Apple(iphone) in node js and why and how can we achieve this?

Tags: ios, iphone, node.js, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to send push-notifications to iphone by using node.js server-side language
I found npm two modules for doing that

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/apns

   ```
   var apns = require("apns"), options, connection, notification;

   options = {
    keyFile : "conf/key.pem",
    certFile : "conf/cert.pem",
    debug : true
   };
   ```

   connection = new apns.Connection(options);

I have only single pem file but they are asking about two pem files key.pem and cert.pem

2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/apn

   ```
     var options = {
       token: {
        key: "path/to/key.p8",
        keyId: "T0K3NK3Y1D",
        teamId: "T34M1D"
     },
     production: false
    };

   var apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);
   ```

In this, they are asking about key, keyId. teamId. But how can I get this ?

Which npm module should I used for sending Apple push notifications ?

I have pem file and bundle id of my app. Are they sufficient to send push notifications to Apple user or not ?

Also can't figure out which npm module is best suited for sending the same ?
Any suggestions are always welcome regarding this.

Thanks for the help

Comment: How to generate key.pem and cert.pem file? Did you get any solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @ishika Yes I got the solution. I used the apns module and the pem files generated by the IOS team. Actually the path I used for pem files is wrong that's why unable to send notification in ios

Answer (score 0):

You have too many subquestions in that question which point to the same question of which npm module to use for sending iOS notifications from node server.

I used APN module from here and it works seamlessly- 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/apn

Apple guide on how APN works-
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

Details on how to create key and certificate files-
https://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_create_APNS_certificates

Hope that helps!

Comment: what is p8 key as I have p12 key

Comment: p8 is the new authentication system key which apple creates now a days. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672297/how-to-use-apples-new-p8-certificate-for-apns-in-firebase-console

Comment: How to generate key.pem and cert.pem file?