# unregistered registration token (firebase ios)

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, apple-push-notifications, firebase-notifications

I would like to ask if someone could help with a problem which i have.
I have generated the Authentication Key (.p8). Also i have set it into the firebase console under the tab "Cloud Messaging".
While i successfully completed the android push notification process, i get stuck on IOS implementation.
I test the APNS with the pusher app and it works just fine. So the certificate is correct.
When i use the firebase console the error is "Unregistered registration token". Of course i use the
token which is generated from firebase plugin and not the token from APNS.
I use xamarin form for the development and the plug in is Plugin.FirebasePushNotification by Rendy Del Rosario. i follow the instructions from the github. 
Below is the code :

code inside the AppDelegate.cs file
// Here is the code to Initialize the FirebasePushNotificationManager

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(options, true);
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```

Function prints the token from APN which i use to send notification from the pusher app. 
The generated token is valid

```
public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            byte[] deviceTokenBytes = deviceToken.ToArray();
            string deviceToken2 = 
            BitConverter.ToString(deviceTokenBytes).Replace("-", enter code 
            here"").ToUpperInvariant();
            Debug.WriteLine("------> " + deviceToken2);

 FirebasePushNotificationManager.DidRegisterRemoteNotifications(deviceToken);
        }
```

inside the App.cs file 
Function print the token which i use to send notification from the firebase console. 
The generated token is invalid and produce an error "Unregistered Registration Token"

```
CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnTokenRefresh += (s, p) =>
            {
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"TOKEN : "+ p.Token
            };
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Did you already [upload your APNS key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#upload_your_apns_authentication_key) to Firebase?

Comment: At first i had uploaded the keys APNs authentication key. Now i use the APNs Certificates. Still nothing.

Comment: @Dennis Can you show the code setup push notification?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672297/how-to-use-apples-new-p8-certificate-for-apns-in-firebase-console

Comment: I have generated the Authentication Key (.p8). Also i have set it into the firebase console under the tab "Cloud Messaging".
I use Plugin.FirebasePushNotification by Rendy Del Rosario. i follow the instructions from the github.